# How to use iciql Model Generation

Tags: java, mysql, database, orm

Now, I tried to make automatically Model Class with [iciql](http://iciql.com/tools.html)'s Model Generation Tools.
I use Windows7.
I tried this command on command prompt.

---

**>cd C:\Users\xxxx\iciql-1.1.0

> java -jar iciql-1.1.0.jar -url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx -user root -password xxxx**

---

and returned this error message.

**Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the message says it all: There's no mysql jdbc driver on the classpath. Download it and use something like

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar -jar iciql-1.1.0.jar \
     -url jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx -user root -password xxxx**
```